# Facebook Like button: can I have a page-specific "like" functionality triggered by a unique (site-wise) button

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

For this project http://www.cinematheque.fr/expositions-virtuelles/kubrick_web/index.php I'm trying to set up a FB like button (see top right) common to all pages.

The Like button iframe:

```
<iframe id="fb" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cinematheque.fr%2Fexpositions-virtuelles%2Fkubrick_web%2Findex.php&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I'm trying to set the OpenGraph meta tags' with values that are page-dependent, in particular the `og:image` (because the website is an artwork gallery, each page showing a different visual work which I want to use as the Like illustration).
Thus, I want to combine the benefits of having one unique Like **counter** for the site with a wide variety of data and illustrations in the FB wall story depending on the actual page you are when clicking the Like button.

The meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Kubrick et le web" />
<meta property="og:type" content="director" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Graphistes, vid&eacute;astes, stylistes, plasticiens : toute une g&eacute;n&eacute;ration de cr&eacute;ateurs talentueux s'est pench&eacute;e depuis 15 ans sur l'&oelig;uvre kubrickienne pour lui rendre hommage, la questionner, la remixer. D&eacute;couvrez notre portfolio, plus de 200 cr&eacute;ations d&eacute;couvertes sur le web." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.cinematheque.fr/expositions-virtuelles/kubrick_web/index.php" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="La Cin&eacute;math&egrave;que fran&ccedil;aise" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="24658885765" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.cinematheque.fr/expositions-virtuelles/kubrick_web/images/600/201-1.jpg" />
```

To be consistent with the `iframe`, I use the same value for the `og:url` tag across the site (= the homepage URL), but that is perhaps wrong.

However, it doesn't work as expected because the FB story doesn't show the correct page-specific illustration but the generic image I've indicated for the homepage.

Could you tell me if what I'm trying to do (one counter / page-wise metadata) is valid and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is semantically wrong. Like button is specific for a object, in your case it should be a particular image that the user likes in your website.

In order to show total likes for your website, you might use the graph api and sum all the likes of all the objects(of all your images).

To count the likes of an object, refer this

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it, somehow.